# Macro not pasting from each file stored in a collection

Tags: excel, vba

My code only returns one files data but not the whole collection.

```
'Collect all data from audit templates
RecursiveDir colFiles, path, "*.xlsm", True
For Each varFile In colFiles
    Set reportBook = Workbooks.Open(varFile)
    Set suSummary = reportBook.Sheets("SU Summaries")
    Do While suSummary.Cells(reportRow, 1) <> "" 'Only report if there are scanned files
        lineNum = lineNum + 1
        With suSummary
            scanDate = FileDateTime(varFile)
            scanned = .Cells(reportRow, 2)
            auditor = .Cells(reportRow, 3)
        End With
        ReDim Preserve reportArray(3, lineNum)
        reportArray(0, lineNum) = scanDate
        reportArray(1, lineNum) = scanned
        reportArray(2, lineNum) = auditor
        reportRow = reportRow + 1
    Loop
reportBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next varFile

'Paste data into Scan Sheet
For lineNum = 1 To UBound(reportArray, 2)
    With scanSheet
        .Cells(baseRow, 1) = reportArray(0, lineNum) 'Date Scanned
        .Cells(baseRow, 2) = reportArray(1, lineNum) 'Scanned
        .Cells(baseRow, 3) = reportArray(2, lineNum) 'Auditor
        .Cells(baseRow, 4).Formula = "=IF(LEN(C" & baseRow & ")>2,TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(C" & baseRow & "),2)),C" & baseRow & ")" 'Auditor1
        .Cells(baseRow, 5).Formula = "=IF(LEN(C" & baseRow & ")>2,TRIM(RIGHT(TRIM(C" & baseRow & "),2)),C" & baseRow & ")" 'Auditor 2
        .Cells(baseRow, 6).Formula = "=B" & baseRow & "/2" 'Average Scanned
        .Cells(baseRow, 7).Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNA(VLOOKUP(D" & baseRow & ",Summary!A:C,1,0)),ISNA(VLOOKUP(E" & baseRow & ",Summary!A:C,1,0))),""MISSING"",""GOOD"")" 'Auditor CK
    End With
    baseRow = baseRow + 1
Next lineNum
```

The macro runs fine and opens up all the workbooks, but it only will paste data from the first workbook instead of all of them.

Comment: Should `reportRow` be reset back to 1 each time you open a new workbook?

Comment: yup i forgot that part, thanks.

Comment: Does resetting `reportRow` to 1 each time you open a workbook fix the problem with only the data from the first workbook being pasted?